# How to resolve "Failed to find SQL table for type" exception on Ignite SqlQuery?

Tags: sql, ignite

I get the exception "Failed to find SQL table for type" when executing a SQL query on an Ignite cache.  An equivalent ScanQuery successfully executes on the same cache.

nb - note from my code that I create the cache after Ignite has been started.  This is deliberate, as I wish to be able to create caches dynamically.

Employee class:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @QuerySqlField (index = true)
    private final Integer empNo;
    @QuerySqlField
    private String name;
    @QuerySqlField
    private Department dept;
    @QuerySqlField
    private Integer salary;
```

Create & populate Employee cache:

```
    CacheConfiguration<Integer, Employee> empCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
    empCacheCfg.setName("Employee");
    IgniteCache<Integer, Employee> empCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(empCacheCfg);

    empCache.put(0, new Employee(0, "Bill", deptCache.get("POT"), 20000));
    empCache.put(1, new Employee(1, "Ben", deptCache.get("POT"), 21000));
    empCache.put(2, new Employee(2, "Little Weed", deptCache.get("PLANT"), 15000));
    empCache.put(3, new Employee(3, "The Gardner", deptCache.get("SVC"), 30000));
```

SQLQuery over Employee cache:

```
    SqlQuery sql = new SqlQuery("Employee", "salary > ?");

    try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Integer, Employee>> cursor2 = 
                    empCache.query(sql.setArgs(20000)))
    {
        for(var e2 : cursor2)
        {
             System.out.println(String.format("Employee: %s", e2.getValue().getName()));                   
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String exmsg = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(exmsg);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify query entities in your cache configuration. They can be configured using the [CacheConfiguration#indexedTypes](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setIndexedTypes-java.lang.Class...-) property.

The following line should fix your example:

```
empCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Employee.class);
```

Documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-by-annotations

Comment: Thanks, Denis.  It does!